# Using the same Transaction for the Endpoint and the DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, nservicebus

I'm building an Asp.Net MVC application. I've used Entity Framework Core for database access. I'm using SQLServer for the database. All the EF Stuff works fine from inside the controller methods.

I also have a related NServiceBus service application that handles things that don't need to run in the web server. One of the common things is performing a task after a timeout. (e.g. A user does something on the website, and 30 minutes later do something.)

I'm using SQL Transport for my service bus setup and its using the same database as the Entity Framework data.

Since the web server doesn't need to handle an NServiceBus messages, it has a Send Only IEndpointInstance registered with the IOC container. Controllers that need to send NServiceBus messages get the IEndpointInstance and use it to send.

Now on the surface this all appears to be working neatly, The controller handles a client request, uses EF to alter the database, and uses the Endpoint to send NServiceBus messages, but there is a problem. While both EF and NServiceBus are using the same SQL database to store data and messages, these tasks aren't part of the same Database transaction. This means that there is the edge case where if things go wrong, for EF to save a change to the database, but then the sending of the NServiceBus message might not complete, and now the data and messages are in an inconsistent state.

So the question is, How do I get the IEndpointInstance to send inside the same transaction as the EF DbContext Save?

I have found that when configuring the EndPoint Transport, there is a UseCustomSqlConnectionFactory extension method that I can use. I've been able to provide a factory that grabs the DbContext used in the web request scope from the IOC container, and extract its SqlConnection and provide that to the Endpoint. The problem here is that the Task returned from IEndpointInstance.Send never returns when I .Wait() for the send to complete.

While there is plenty of documentation and examples out there about sharing the transaction contained in IMessageHandlerContext with EF, I can't find anything about getting IEndpointInstance to share a transaction with EF.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do so. You can implement a UnitOfWork on top of the DbContext and integrate that with the message handler pipeline. This assures that if you have multiple handlers, they'll all participate in the same transaction. This approach will work with a send only endpoint as well as the send and receive (given the underlying transport supports that), although you'll need to change the behavior to execute at a different time for a send-only endpoint (as obviously there's no 'incoming' message for a send-only endpoint).

The way you do that is that you inject a behavior into the message processing pipeline when a message comes in:

```
public class UnitOfWorkSetupBehaviorBehavior : Behavior<IIncomingLogicalMessageContext>
{
    public override async Task Invoke(IIncomingLogicalMessageContext context, Func<Task> next)
    {
        var uow = new EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork();
        context.Extensions.Set(uow);
        await next().ConfigureAwait(false); //executes the next op in the chain
        context.Extensions.Remove<EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork>();
    }
}
```

And the actual unit of work implementation would be like this (note that it uses the ambient transaction):

```
class EntityFrameworkUnitOfWork
{
    MyDataContext context;

    public MyDataContext GetDataContext(SynchronizedStorageSession storageSession)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            var dbConnection = storageSession.Session().Connection;
            context = new MyDataContext (dbConnection);

            //Don't use transaction because connection is enlisted in the TransactionScope
            context.Database.UseTransaction(null);

            //Call SaveChanges before completing storage session
            storageSession.OnSaveChanges(x => context.SaveChangesAsync());
        }
        return context;
    }
}
```

If this all seems too daunting, there is a great sample you can [download](https://docs.particular.net/samples/entity-framework/?version=core_7) on the documentation website.

Comment: I'm missing something. The behavior isn't invoked until I call IEndpointInstance.Send(), which means the Unit of Work is not Added to Extensions until then. Likewise, How am I supposed to access the Extensions Get before Send() is called?

Comment: The process I'm trying to accomplish in my MVC Controller is:
1. Query the business data DB Context
2. Decide to Exit or Continue
3. Update the business data DB Context
4. Send a message.

So How can I create a business DB Context using the connection object from the endpoint instance if that connection isn't exposed in a behavior until Sending?

Comment: @WilliamLeader Wouldn't a TransactionScope help in that case? As long as you share the database that contains the messages + business data with EXACT same connection string, they would both participate in the same transaction (without escalating to DTC).